# Adding the files to the installation in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

We have set of .txt files added to the resources in the visual studio framework.Now we create the installer for this framework and we want these file to be created at the specified path for ex:C:\Program Files (x86) by creating the folder with the framework name and putting the files in that folder and we want to access only the file path during runtime and not the file contents .so how can we achieve this in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
string FilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + @"\Resources\fileName.txt";
```

Comment: Using this is giving nullrefrence exception

Comment: check if the file is present there in the resources folder

Comment: Debug it and check if the path it's giving is correct or not